# Why withLatestFrom RxJS method not static?

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

The RxJS [withLatestFrom](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/withlatestfrom.md) is an instance method. An instance of an Observable has to be newed up/created to call the method.

The [merge](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/merge.md) method is a static method. There is no need of an instance needed.

Why the RxJS `withLatestFrom` is not a static method but an instance method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a good example is the `combineLatest` operator that exists as both static and instance method. The order of source Observables to `combineLatest` doesn't matter. Its internals work the same way and the output is going to be the same (just the order of values in the resulting array is going to be different which is irrelevant). The same applies to `concat`, `merge`, `zip`, `forkJoin` and so on.

However with the `withLatestFrom` operator it's different and the order of Observables matters. There's one source Observable that controls when the operator emits. If you changed the order it'd produces different results. For example if you had the following:

```
Observable.withLatestFrom(o1, o2, o3)
```

This means you could also use the following:

```
Observable.withLatestFrom(...observables)
```

Now you can't know which Observable is the source and it's going to be hard to debug what's going on.

So the reason why there's no `Observable.withLatestFrom` static method is because it doesn't make much sense. The order of Observables matters and it'd make things just more obfuscated.

For the same reason other operators such as `buffer` or `window` don't have their static forms even though there's no technical limitation. It'd just allow you to write more imperative code instead of simply chaining operators.

Answer (score 2):

`withLatestFrom` is different from `merge`, because it has the concept of a canonical "source" observable, which is augmented by the latest value from another observable. `merge` is not "hierarchical" like this, observables are just combined as equals into a single stream.